# How to pass multiple argument in angular js rest call

Tags: angularjs, rest, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Trying to implemnt rest call in angular  js using   $http.get() method and passing multiple parameter but it is throwing 
error

```
  var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);


    app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {


        $http.get("https://api.nexmo.com/verify/json?api_key=56a9bn1af&api_secret=d3n0de241&number=919690286358&brand=stayuncle");

    });
```

Error is :

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 364; columnNumber: 85; The reference to entity "api_secret" must end with the ';' delimiter.
```

Any possible work around?

Comment: You should pass it as an object and stringfy it.

Comment: @Rohit Hi can you made changes in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can try the following, I'm away from a computer so can't try and suggest for sure.

var obj = {
api_key=56a9bn1af,
api_secret=d3n0de241,
number=919690286358,
brand="stayuncle"
};

$http.get("https://api.nexmo.com/verify/json?param=" + json.stringfy(obj));

From checking the API, I think you have to try this -

```
"https://api.nexmo.com/verify/json?api_key={api_key}&api_secret={api_secret}&number=447525856424&brand=MyApp"
```

Comment: What is the parameters the api is expecting? Is it yours?

Comment: now error has revoed and fuction calling is not happening. getting this erro in chrome web console :Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] ::

@line  var obj = { api_key=56ab1af, api_secret=d0de241, number=919600286358, brand="stayuncle" };
getting  error is "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =" in chrome web console.

Comment: its 3rd party api. this api which i am trying to implement for OTP implementation using angular js .  https://docs.nexmo.com/index.php/verify/verify